# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'XYZ_DEV')

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to host a web application on AWS EC2 Ubuntu t1.micro instance.

MySQL version: 5.5.35

Tomcat version: 7.0.52

JDK version: 7.0_51

The context for the webapp is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/XYZ" docBase="XYZ"
        debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">

<Resource name="jdbc/XYZ" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/XYZ?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    username="root" maxActive="100" maxIdle="50" removeAbandoned="true"
    useUnicode="true" autoReconnect="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"
    password="root"/>
</Context>
```

The error that gets thrown when i start tomcat is as follows

```
AbandonedObjectPool is used (org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool@3f445d30)


LogAbandoned: true
   RemoveAbandoned: true
   RemoveAbandonedTimeout: 60
 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:71) - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:72) - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'XYZ')
 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] (SettingsFactory.java:103) - Could not obtain connection metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'XYZ')
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:855)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:805)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:745)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:245)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'XYZ'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:290)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:877)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:851)
    ... 33 more
```

My AWS security groups are set as follows

```
Type     Protocol     PortRange    Source
MYSQL    TCP          3306         127.0.0.1/32
SSH      TCP          22           0.0.0.0/0
HTTP     TCP          22           0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS    TCP          22           0.0.0.0/0
All traffic      TCP          22           0.0.0.0/0
```

I checked the host that MySQL is running on

```
$ netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

If I try connecting to MySQL using

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -D database_name -p
```

the connection works just fine.

Everything seems to be ok. Still I cant seem to find the reason the error is being thrown.
Would really appreciate some expert advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.
The reason I was getting the error is due to Linux version of MySQL being case sensitive to the database name. When I moved my entire stack from Windows to Linux I faced this problem.

Windows MySQL database names are not case-sensitive and Linux MySQL database names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Below rule is redundant. So remove it.

```
MYSQL    TCP          3306         127.0.0.1/32
```

---

Your MySQL is listening on only localhost:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

This is not a problem as long as you are connecting to MySQL locally. But any remote connection to MySQl will fails. If this is the case, then change the MySQL binding to `0.0.0.0` in `my.cnf`.

---

Before running you code, could you try connecting to the MySQL locally using the MySQL cli as below:

```
mysql -u <username> -h 127.0.0.1 -p
```

If this connection works fine, then check whether you are able to connect fine with your `jdbc` driver. Also, double check your `jdbc` settings.

Comment: I have tried connecting to mysql using host ip 127.0.0.1. It works fine. Since I have added ALL TRAFFIC in my AWS security group I know adding MYSQL is redundant but that was just in case. How do I check the connection using jdbc driver? And where do I check jdbc settings. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not a java guy. Check these links which will help you testing JDBC: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html, http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/JDBC_and_MySQL